# VB .Net Multiple Instances of same for with Events

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to open multiple instances of the same form based on rows selected from a DataGridView.
My current code works, but waits for each form to close before going onto the next.
I need to open the forms at the same time, but still have them report back to the main form via events.

```
Public Class frmARLog
    Private WithEvents edit As frmEditARLog
    'WithEvents: indicate that we want to receive events raised by this object

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        fill()
    End Sub

    Sub fill()
        Dim AR As AltARLog = New AltARLog

        dgvARLog.DataSource = AR.getTable

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
        Dim iRowIndex As Integer
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvARLog.SelectedCells.Count - 1

            iRowIndex = dgvARLog.SelectedCells.Item(i).RowIndex
            openEditForm(dgvARLog.Rows(iRowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString, iRowIndex)
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub openEditForm(arid As Integer, row As Integer)
        edit = New frmEditARLog(arid)
        AddHandler edit.FormClosing, AddressOf ItIsClosing
        AddHandler edit.FormClosed, AddressOf ItIsClosed
        edit.ShowDialog(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ItIsClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs)
        If edit.Successful Then
            fill()
        End If
        RemoveHandler edit.FormClosing, AddressOf ItIsClosing
    End Sub

    Private Sub ItIsClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs)
        RemoveHandler edit.FormClosed, AddressOf ItIsClosed
        edit = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `edit.ShowDialog(Me)` you are telling it to lock the calling form as you would with a dialog display.

You want to change this line to: `edit.Show(Me)`

Another note, you will are only allowing for one reference to a child from in this code. You may want to consider if you need to store a reference to all forms or not.

I would suggest not storing them. Register your events and then show. The events will still fire as expected, you will then need to use the `sender` argument of your event `Sub`, this will be the calling child form.

Insert this as the first line of each of your event handlers.

```
Dim frmEditARLog edit as frmEditARLog = DirectCast(sender, frmEditARLog)
```

Comment: Any suggestions on a resource to go about registering events.

Comment: You cna register the events just as you do now.